# Find missing onError in the project

Tags: android, rx-java

I am trying to locate a missing `onError()` in a project. It means that the app crashes because a subscription does not handle the throwables so I want to locate that subcription and add the onError method.

Unfortunatelly the stacktrace is not really helpful here and it only shows the line of the `throw new IOException` but nothing more:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: my.app.example.dev, PID: 20309
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread.
            at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:54)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorFailedException: Error occurred when trying to propagate error to Observer.onError
            at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:201)
            at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:111)
            at rx.android.app.OperatorConditionalBinding$1.onError(OperatorConditionalBinding.java:69)
            at rx.internal.operators.NotificationLite.accept(NotificationLite.java:147)
            at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.pollQueue(OperatorObserveOn.java:177)
            at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.access$000(OperatorObserveOn.java:65)
            at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber$2.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:153)
            at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:47)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: rx.exceptions.CompositeException: 2 exceptions occurred.
            at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:201)
            at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:111)
            at rx.android.app.OperatorConditionalBinding$1.onError(OperatorConditionalBinding.java:69)
            at rx.internal.operators.NotificationLite.accept(NotificationLite.java:147)
            at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.pollQueue(OperatorObserveOn.java:177)
            at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.access$000(OperatorObserveOn.java:65)
            at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber$2.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:153)
            at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:47)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: rx.exceptions.CompositeException$CompositeExceptionCausalChain: Chain of Causes for CompositeException In Order Received =>
            at com.splunk.mint.ExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(ExceptionHandler.java:42)
            at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
            at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
            at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:58)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: retrofit.RetrofitError: java.io.IOException: No connectivity
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:385)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:221)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$1.call(RestAdapter.java:271)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$1.call(RestAdapter.java:269)
            at retrofit.RxSupport$2.run(RxSupport.java:46)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: No connectivity
            at my.app.example.manager.ApiManager$NetworkAwareOKClient.execute(ApiManager.java:1071)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:322)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:221)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$1.call(RestAdapter.java:271)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$1.call(RestAdapter.java:269)
            at retrofit.RxSupport$2.run(RxSupport.java:46)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Any ideas to locate the subscription (line in code) that does not have the `onError()` ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This can be a pain to debug. Funnily enough I had an error inside the `Action1<Throwable>` [facepalm].

The best was to debug this is to register a global error handler. This will saw you the truth in your code:

```
RxJavaPlugins.getInstance().registerErrorHandler(new RxJavaErrorHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handleError(Throwable e) {
            Log.w("Error",e);
        }
});
```

A discussion on github: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/2293

Comment: I added the code above and I did got the log.w error message, but the app still got crash. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @User9527 did you remove any subscription invocation from the subscriber (onNext, onError, onComplete)? If not you should ofc do so :)

Comment: @Diolor, I registered a global ErrorHandler, I can catch the error. But the App still crash. Finally I I added onError, onComplete, it never crash again. thank you for your help.

Comment: @Diolor I'd use a library called [RxLint](https://bitbucket.org/littlerobots/rxlint), which checks for the missing `onError` implementations and reports it.

Comment: I implemented in my code but the message of the throwable arriving is null. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

If the onError is not implemented, then RxJava throw a `OnErrorNotImplementedException` exception. It's seems that RxJava didn't succed to call the `onError` method ("Error occurred when trying to propagate error to Observer.onError")

You can try to register an error handler to find the root exception.

```
static {
    RxJavaPlugins.getInstance().registerErrorHandler(new RxJavaErrorHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handleError(Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:

```
RxJavaHooks.setOnError(throwable -> {
    if (throwable != null && throwable.getMessage() != null) {
        Log.e("Error", throwable.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Instead of deprecated `RxJavaPlugins.getInstance()`